# Android - How to finish a child activity from a parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a first activity A where I start a new activity B with:

`intent.setClass(A.this, B.class);`

Now, after some event, I would like to finish B from A (A contains a running thread).

How could I reach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a little more about what your two activities ( A and B ) are trying to accomplish? If you are needing to finish() B from inside of A, it seems like there might be a better way accomplish your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can send broadcast message from A to B
2. Do you need to use B as Activity instance in these terms? may be better choice is to create B as dialog?

Comment: Thank you @rdbmsa. After your answer I have researched a little in order implement a broadcast pattern and now my Frankenstein works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The `Activity` will be finished by the OS when memory resources are low.

Also, clicking the back button calls `finish()` on the current activity and displays the top activity in the backstack, so presumably you will have already finished the child.

Comment: with respect to _...when memory resources are low_ Could you help me by tell me which method about the Activity's life cycle is called just before an activity will be finished?

Comment: @Jorgesmash `onStop()` is the last call you are guaranteed to get from the system. `onDestroy()` exists, but doesn't always get called.